# What is the extra set of parentheses for

Tags: javascript, nested-function

I've been learning JavaScript and AngularJS and have been seeing functions with an extra set of parentheses. What is this? How does it work?
    e.g.: `myFunc(args)(moreArgs)`.

Comment: Hard to tell with such code, but it might be that `myFunc(args)` returns a function.

Comment: Could you provide an example in wild?

Comment: @Dmitry not sure on the example.. I thought what I provided was the example. I just ran across it and wasn't sure how it worked.

Comment: To close voters: what about this question is unclear? These is only one way to parse the statement provided under the ECMAScript grammar, and even if it *were* somehow grammatically ambiguous, the identifier names (`myFunc`, `args`) make it quite clear how the statement is intended to be read. This question is perfectly comprehensible and answerable as-is, as evidenced by the two correct answers already posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra set is for running and returning another function. So, using your example: `myFunc` will take one argument and return a second function (can be anonymously named):

```
function myFunc(args) {
  return function (moreArgs) {
    return args + ' ' + moreArgs;
  };
}

var myMsg = myFunc("This")("works!");
alert(myMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes since seeing the actual function. Does this mean you can return more than one function?

Comment: Honestly, I know you can return more functions than what I demostrated above, but I'm not sure what the limit is (if any). I would expect you can return as many as you would need to, but I'm not sure how practical that would be.

Comment: @myPClovesME A function can return only one value at a time. You could nest returned functions, though. Here, we have a function that returns a function that returns a string. We could have instead a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns a string. (Or a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns a function that returns...)

Comment: @myPClovesME Consider also the possibility of returning unlimited functions with a function that returns itself: `function foo(done) { if(done) { return "all done"; } else { return foo; } }` You could call this with `foo(false)(false)(false)(false)(false)(true);`.

Comment: @apsillers That is really neat. Thank you everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a function can return a function and that returned function can be called immediately. For example:

```
function a () {
    return function () {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

One way of calling the returned function is:

```
var b = a(); // b is now a function returned by a
b(); // logs "hello"
```

But in javascript you can also do:

```
a()(); // calls the returned function immediately, logs "hello"
```